# Android GridView Set Focus to First EditText

Tags: android, gridview, focus, android-edittext

I have a GridView that is populated by a layout containing an ImageView and an EditText.

When the activity is opened, is there a simple way to set the focus to the first EditText and pop open the keyboard?

Answer (score 10):

After you create the view and set the content do the following

```
setContentView(R.Layout.main);
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText01);
edit.requestFocus();
```

That should do it.

EDIT: After rereading your post I realize you might be trying to access the item on the grid view in which case the above will not work.  Try this instead

```
GridView myGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
ViewGroup griditem = (ViewGroup) myGridView.getChildAt(0); //First item
for(int i = 0; i < griditem.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    if(griditem.getChildAt(i) instaceof TextView)
        griditem.getChildAt(i).requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: The gridview contains several instances of the layout that contains the EditText.  The EditText lies in a different layout than the main layout of the activity. Reread my question. How do I specifically obtain the first EditText (within the GridView) ?

Comment: Ive updated my post with a fix that should work for what you need.

Comment: I get a nullPointerException on the for statement's line